# Unable to retrieve downloaded file through azure pipeline

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to download a pdf file while running my selenium test through the azure pipeline and then I want to retrieve the downloaded file but while doing that I am getting below exception

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/test/resources/MyPdf.pdf (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream.<init>(RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream.java:99)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1079)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1041)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:989)
```

**Selenium code:**

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("googlegeolocationaccess.enabled", false);
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation", 2); // 1:allow 2:block
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings", 1);
prefs.put("download.default_directory",  System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "test" + File.separator + "resources");
chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

**yml file:**

```
jobs:
      - job: Test Running
        timeoutInMinutes: 180
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
        continueOnError: true
        steps:
          - task: Gradle@2
            displayName: Run Tests against UK Region
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              tasks: test
```

The above code is working fine on my windows machine and saving file project directory (C:\Selenium\src\test\resources) but through the pipeline, it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

The path supplied for selenium's `download.defaultdirectory` is different from the path you get in the error when retrieving the files. This is because `System.getProperty("user.dir")` gets the home directory for the current user (*vsts*) and that is `/home/vsts`.

So with the path statement in Selenium code you would get: `/home/vsts/src/test/resources/` as the default download directory.